# How to call an JFrog Artifactory user plugin as non-admin user

Tags: plugins, permissions, artifactory, http-status-code-403

I'm writing my first Artifactory user plugin which should be callable via REST. Here is a part of the implementation:

```
executions {

    repoInfo(httpMethod: 'GET') { params ->

    ....
```

I can call the plugin successfully as the admin user:

```
$ curl -u admin:XXX -X GET "http://localhost:8080/artifactory/api/plugins/execute/repoInfo"
```

but when calling it as another user I get http return code 403 in return:

```
curl -u test-user-1:XXX -X GET "http://localhost:8080/artifactory/api/plugins/execute/repoInfo"{  
    "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 403,
    "message" : "You are not permitted to execute 'repoInfo'."
   } 
   ]
}
```

My question is what permissions do I need to assign to test-user-1 in order to being able to access my plugin ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained somewhat unclearly in the [docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Executions):

```
  /**
   * An execution definition.
   * The first value is a unique name for the execution.
   *
   * ...
   *
   * Plugin info annotation parameters:
   *  ...
   *  users (java.util.Set<java.lang.String>) - Users permitted to query this plugin for information or invoke it.
   *  groups (java.util.Set<java.lang.String>) - Groups permitted to query this plugin for information or invoke it.
   *
   * ...
   */

  myExecution(version:version, description:description, httpMethod: 'GET', users:[], groups:[], params:[:]) { params ->
  }
```

There are a number of optional parameters you can pass when creating an execution plugin, two of which are `users` and `groups`. If these are omitted or empty, then only admin users can execute plugins. If you want non-admin users to execute a plugin, you need to add usernames to the `users` list or group names to the `groups` list. For example:

```
executions {
    repoInfo(httpMethod: 'GET', users: ['tom', 'bill'], groups: ['dev-team']) { params ->
        // ...
    }
}
```

In this case, the people who can use this plugin are `tom`, `bill`, anyone in the `dev-team` group, and anyone with admin privileges.

---

Sometimes it makes sense to make a plugin available for anyone and everyone to use. To do this, you would generally do something like:

```
executions {
    publicRepoInfo(httpMethod: 'GET', groups: ['readers']) { params ->
        // ...
    }
}
```

Artifactory installs with a pre-existing group called `readers`, which is automatically added to all new users and gives them basic read access, so all logged-in users should be part of this group. All users that are not logged in are considered to be logged in as the special `anonymous` user, which is also part of the `readers` group.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and detailed explanation. It's working like a charm.